# Sending through SMTP to same domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, smtp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IIS SMTP server (Installed on local server) in parallel to Google Apps](https://serverfault.com/questions/123450/iis-smtp-server-installed-on-local-server-in-parallel-to-google-apps)

We have a website set up for www.clientname.com(and also clientname.com), running on a windows server 2008 machine.  It's running IIS and has SMTP installed.

The client is using google apps for their email @clientname.com

The website sends mail through .net code, which sends out through the local SMTP server.  Recently a problem came up.

When the website is sending out an email to address@clientname.com, instead of actually sending out the email, the SMTP service will drop the .eml file into c:/wwwroot/mailroot/drop

If I send out an email myself, it makes it to the clients email.

What is causing the SMTP service to do this?

Comment: See this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/123450/iis-smtp-server-installed-on-local-server-in-parallel-to-google-apps

Comment: Thanks, I think that did it.  I was having a hard time trying to search for this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have clientname.com set up as a local domain on the W2K8 SMTP server when in fact it should be set up as a remote domain.